# How to call on a renamed file in another function? (Visual C++)

Tags: file, visual-c++

So, I'm trying to create a text file that can be written to and used to seed a random number generator, but I need to be able to write to and call on the file in all of my functions. The file has to be named with the user's first and last name so I found some code that would create a text file and rename it, I'm just having trouble calling the file in my other functions. I included the beginning part of one of my other functions after the code for the text file creation. I'm going to need to send a time stamp to the file and use that time to seed my RNG.

int user_file_name()
{

```
string tstamp = get_timestamp();

//Creating input/output file using user's name

ofstream user_file;
string filename;

cout << "What is your first and last name?\n" << endl;
getline(cin, filename);
filename += ".txt";

cout << "Thank you, " << filename << "." << endl << endl;

user_file.open(filename.c_str());
user_file << tstamp;
user_file.close();

return 0;
```

}

int addition()
{

```
char DIFFICULTY;

difficulty_menu();
cin >> DIFFICULTY;

get_timestamp();
string tstamp = get_timestamp();
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just have `user_file_name` return the `string` filename instead of just an int?  You can then store that filename somewhere so that other areas of your program can access it.